# Leer valores JSON, objetos dentro de objeto

Tags: android, android-studio, json

Quiero leer este JSON:

```
{"0":{"0":"13"},"1":{"0":"23"},"2":{"0":"34"},"3":{"0":"46"},"4":{"0":"57"}}
```

Lo intento hacer con este bucle:

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

```
                int iden;
                int id[] = new int[json.length()];

                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject ide = json.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(id[i]));
                    iden= ide.getInt("0");

                }
```

Pero solo me saca el primer valor(13)

Comment: JSON tiene dos asuntos claves, para poder entenderlo. Si lo comprendes, comprenderás todo. Se trata de esto: `{}` y de esto: `[]`. Lo primero representaría un objeto JSON, lo segundo representa un array json, que agruparía un conjunto de valores, que pueden ser objetos JSON, o primarios (cadenas, números, boolenaos). En tu caso, no puedes leer esos datos ocn un `for`, por algo muy simple: tu actual objeto no es un array JSON. Para leer ese objeto tendrías que acceder por cada clave: `0`, `1`, `2`... porque no está organizado como un array ...

Comment: ... Un array sería: `[{"0":"13"},{"0":"23"},{"0":"34"},{"0":"46"},{"0":"57"}]` (considera lo que decía al principio, lo de `{}` y lo de `[]`). Aquí, si observas, el objeto empieza por `[` y termina por `]`, eso indica que es un array. Y si miras dentro de ambos símbolos, verás que dicho array tiene dentro varios objetos json (delimitado cada uno por `{}`). En ese caso sí podrás leer el objeto en un bucle `for` sin ningún problema. Si has entendido esto, no tendrás más problemas con JSON, por más complejo que este sea. Este es el ABC de JSON. Si no lo entiendes, perderás horas, días, semanas...

Answer (score 0):

La estructura de tu json es un objeto que contiene dentro varios objetos:

```
{
  "0": {
    "0": "13"
  },
  "1": {
    "0": "23"
  },
  "2": {
    "0": "34"
  },
  "3": {
    "0": "46"
  },
  "4": {
    "0": "57"
  }
}
```

En este caso primeramente puedes obtener los nombres de los objetos a partir del `JSONObject` padre :

```
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

  JSONArray array = json.names();
```

el array resultante contendrá los nombres de cada objeto, e iterarías en base a este array:

```
["0","1","2","3","4"]
```

Esta sería la forma para obtener los valores:

```
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
    int iden;
    JSONArray array = json.names();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject ide = null;
        ide = json.getJSONObject(array.get(i).toString());
        iden = ide.getInt("0");
        
        System.out.println("iden: " + iden);
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

tendrías como salida:

```
13
23
34
46
57
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok el json que recibes viene dentro de un objeto lo primero que tienes que hacer es declarar tu objeto y pasarle el json en formato String (si es que lo recibes asi, si puedes pasarle el objeto json tambien funciona), despues vas extrayendo cada valor, en mi caso lo estoy guardando en 5 variables: valor0 a valor4.

```
private void decifrarJSON(String jsonRecibido){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonRecibido);
        String valor0 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("0").getString("0");
        String valor1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("1").getString("0");
        String valor2 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("2").getString("0");
        String valor3 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("3").getString("0");
        String valor4 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("4").getString("0");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Te da como resultado:

```
valor0 = "13", valor1 = "23", valor2 = "34", valor3 = "46", valor4 = "57"
```

Answer (score -1):

El array de enteros no es necesario, prueba con esto:

```
int iden;
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject ide = json.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));
    iden= ide.getInt("0");
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cómo piensas calcular `json.length()` en ese caso? Si no es un array no sabrás jamás cuantos objetos hay dentro. Voto en contra de tu respuesta por eso.

Comment: @A.Cedano Intentalo, funciona

Comment: Realmente no lo he probado, ni tengo posibilidad de hacerlo ahora. De todos modos tu código no debería funcionar. Por ejemplo, usas `getInt()` cuando el dato, según el JSON de la pregunta es una cadena, está rodeado de comillas, si fuese un entero, no tendría comillas. De modo que el método debería ser `getString()`. Como quiera que sea, JSON existe para facilitar el trabajo, guardando datos estructurados que se puedan leer con facilidad, mapear a clases, etc. La estructura JSON que presenta OP no va por ese camino, así que no le animaría, para este caso, a prescindir de un array.

Comment: puede funcionar, pero si los nombres de los objetos no fueran consecutivos o numéricos esto fallaría :|

Comment: @A.Cedano Desde luego que usar un JSON array es lo ideal, pero desconocemos las circunstancias por las que deba leer el JSON de esa forma, nunca lo anime a prescindir de un JSON array, sino de una array de enteros que esta declarando y que no tiene uso. Lo probe imprimiendo en el logcat y funciona, pero como dice Jorgesys, solo funciona para este caso especifico.